# Not able to setup a local npm repo

Tags: npm, npmjs

I wrote a library and I want to test that people can import it from npm and use it as expected. Towards this I set up a local NPM repo like

```
npm install -g local-npm
npm set registry http://127.0.0.1:5080
local-npm
```

This started a local repository on my computer. Now I went to my library project and I did

```
npm publish
```

but I get an error

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth auth required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

I did

```
npm adduser
```

but I get an error

```
npm adduser
Username: foo
Password:
Email: (this IS public) foo@bar.com
npm ERR! code EAUTHIP
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/.npm/_logs/2018-04-07T17_46_18_631Z-debug.log
```

For this local repo. I don't want any users etc because this is only for testing. I want to be able to straight publish to this without any credentials or users. is that possible?

Also, another question is that now that I have setup a local npm and I do a `npm i react -D` in my project the installation would fail because this repository doesn't contain react. So is it possible that when someone does `npm i react -D` it still goes to the original NPM repository when when I do `npm i foo-lib -D` only then it comes to my repository as a fallback because the original npm repository doesn't contain my foo-lib it was only published to this local repository.

Edit: I tried `npm publish --registry http://127.0.0.1:5800` and I got the following error

```
0/bin/npm" "publish" "--registry" "http://127.0.0.1:5080"
23 verbose node v9.5.0
24 verbose npm  v5.7.1
25 error code ENEEDAUTH
26 error need auth auth required for publishing
27 error need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

So it won't let me create a user and it won't let me publish without a user.

Edit2:: I tried the other way round as well.

First run `local-npm` now when the server starts up

from another window do

```
npm set registry http://127.0.0.1:5080
npm publish --registry http://127.0.0.1:5080
npm publish
```

everything results in

```
~/IdeaProjects/t > npm publish --registry http://127.0.0.1:5080
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth auth required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users//.npm/_logs/2018-04-07T18_32_53_815Z-debug.log
~/IdeaProjects/t > npm adduser
Username: foo
Password:
Email: (this IS public) foo@bar.com
npm ERR! code EAUTHIP
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users//.npm/_logs/2018-04-07T18_33_25_737Z-debug.log
```

file contents

```
19 verbose argv "/Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node" "/Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/npm" "adduser"
20 verbose node v9.5.0
21 verbose npm  v5.7.1
22 error code EAUTHIP
23 error Unable to authenticate, need: Basic
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm publish --registry http://127.0.0.1:5080
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry#can-i-run-my-own-private-registry

Comment: Hmm... very strage, they also didn't mention anything about add user at https://github.com/local-npm/local-npm

Comment: Can you paste debug log?

Comment: updated my question above. put the contents of the log.

Comment: At local-npm README they first starting local npm ("local-npm" command) and then changing registry ("npm set registry http://127.0.0.1:5080"). You did it opposite way, maybe that's the issue